# receiving the error: " undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)' " when linking a C++ application with GTK 3.0

Tags: c++, netbeans, gtk, linker-errors, gtk3

I am trying to compile and run an "Hello World" basic example of a C++ application based on GTK 3.0 library, in Linux Mint 21.1 (Vera).

I have solved all the errors of "unresolved #include <...>", by adding explicit paths to the relevant library directories, and as far as I understand the compiler manages to compile.
Now I am faced with an error from the linker, that says:

```
undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)'
```

and

```
undefined reference to `sigc::trackable::trackable()'
```

and several other `undefined reference` errors that I assume are related to the same cause.

The header file helloworld.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H

#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{

public:
  HelloWorld();
  virtual ~HelloWorld();

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_button_clicked();

  //Member widgets:
  Gtk::Button m_button;
};

#endif
```

and the main.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <iostream>

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
: m_button("Hello World")   // creates a new button with label "Hello World".
{
  // Sets the border width of the window.
  set_border_width(10);

  // When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
  // on_button_clicked() method defined below.
  m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));

  // This packs the button into the Window (a container).
  add(m_button);

  // The final step is to display this newly created widget...
  m_button.show();
}

HelloWorld::~HelloWorld()
{
}

void HelloWorld::on_button_clicked()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output on the terminal when I use NetBeans:

```
cd '/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_gtk
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0)    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_gtk build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib -L/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -L/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -L/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -L/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -L/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atkmm-1.6/include -L/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -L/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/pango-1.0 -L/usr/include/harfbuzz -L/usr/include/cairo -L/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 --cflags gtk+-3.0 )
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
/usr/bin/ld: build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: in function `HelloWorld::HelloWorld()':
/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Gtk::Button::Button(Glib::ustring const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `Gtk::Container::set_border_width(unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `Gtk::Button::signal_clicked()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `sigc::connection::~connection()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `Gtk::Container::add(Gtk::Widget&)'

[...] removed big part of the errors, to stay within limits [...]


/usr/bin/ld: build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI10HelloWorld[_ZTI10HelloWorld]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Gtk::Window'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_gtk] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fabio/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_GTK'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I have tried with NetBeans IDE (version 20, installed using a deb package downloaded from the Apache website), adding the following paths in the preferences of the project, both in the C++ Compiler section 'include directories', and in the Linker section 'Additional Library Directories':

```
/usr/include/atk-1.0;/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib;/usr/include/gtk-3.0;/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm;/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0;/usr/include/glibmm-2.4;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include;/usr/include/sigc++-2.0;/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm;/usr/include/freetype2;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include;/usr/include/pangomm-1.4;/usr/include/cairomm-1.0;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atkmm-1.6/include;/usr/include/atkmm-1.6;/usr/include/giomm-2.4;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/include/pango-1.0;/usr/include/harfbuzz;/usr/include/cairo;/usr/include/freetype2;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/include/atk-1.0;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0;/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm;/usr/include/atk-1.0
```

(note that the repetitions are needed in order to solve all the `unresolved #include <...>` errors; I reached this conclusion after a long process of trials and errors).

I have also tried to compile and link via the terminal, giving the following command:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0)    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_gtk build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib -L/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -L/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -L/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -L/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -L/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atkmm-1.6/include -L/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -L/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/pango-1.0 -L/usr/include/harfbuzz -L/usr/include/cairo -L/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 -L/usr/include/glib-2.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -L/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm -L/usr/include/atk-1.0 $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 --cflags gtk+-3.0 )
```

and I have tried to invert the order of the `--libs` and `--cflags` in both `$(pkg-config ...)` instances.

Comment: Do you have the `libgtk-3-dev` and `libgtkmm-3.0-dev` packages installed?  Then all you should need are `$(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 <gtkmm-name>)` and `$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 <gtkmm-name>)` (I don't have gtkmm installed, don't know it's name).

Comment: @BradLanam yes, I have read about that, and I have tried, but the problem stays.

Comment: Why does your linker command contain `$(pkgconfig --cflags ...`?  Those should only be required for compiling.  The linker command should probably end with `$(pkgconfig --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 <sigc>)` where `<sigc>` denotes the appropriate name for the `sigc` library you're using.

Comment: @G.M. I have followed your advice, and I have tried the following:

g++ $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 libgtkmm-3.0 )    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_gtk build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o  $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 libsigc++-2.0 )

But I still get the "undefined reference" error...

Comment: Try linking from the command line.  What's the output from `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 libsigc++-2.0`?